# Replace specific characters in string in Swift

Tags: swift, replace, swift3

I am currently trying to replace specific characters in a string using Swift 3.

```
var str = "Hello"    
var replace = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "Hello", with: "_____")    
print(replace)
```

This will print: _____ but my problem occurs when str changes and consists of a different number of characters or several words such as:

```
var str = "Hello World"
```

Now I want the replace variable to update automatically when `str` is changed. All characters except 'Space' should be replaced with _ and later print _____ _____ which is supposed to represent Hello World.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace all word characters, you can use the `regularExpressions` input to the `options` parameter of the same function you were using before, just change the specific String input to `\\w`, which will match any word characters.

```
let str = "Hello World"
let replace = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\w", with: "_", options: .regularExpression) // "_____ _____"
```

Bear in mind that the `\\w` won't replace other special characters either, so for an input of `"Hello World!"`, it will produce `"_____ _____!"`. If you want to replace every character but whitespaces, use `\\S`.

```
let replace = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\S", with: "_", options: .regularExpression)
```

Answer (score 1):

> All characters except 'Space' should be replaced with _

There are several options. You can `map()` each character to its replacement, and combine the result to a string:

```
let s = "Swift is great"
let t = String(s.map { $0 == " " ? $0 : "_" })
print(t) // _____ __ _____
```

Or use regular expressions, `\S` is the pattern for “not a whitespace character”:

```
let t = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\S", with: "_", options: .regularExpression)
print(t) // _____ __ _____
```

Comment: This is Swift 4. If you are really still using Swift 3 then it would be something like `String(s.characters.map { ... })`